# Exit from full screen not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, fullscreen

I'm working on a application which works in full screen mode.
I'm using a Iframe to go to fullscreen. the problem is how to close that fullscreen on button click?

I'm using this code:

```
function exitfs(){
    if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
        document.cancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
}
```

It works fine if i run it through firebug console but not works when bind with click event?

```
 function fullscreen(keys) {
    var f = e('newIfrane');
    if (keys) {
        if (f.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            f.mozRequestFullScreenWithKeys();
        } else if (f.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            f.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (f.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            f.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (f.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            f.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

calling this function like `fullscreen(false);`

**Note:** Iframe is loading the same page in fullscreen mode. 
In Page there is a Image on click of that image I'm calling  **exitfs()**.

I'm not getting what is the problem?
Thanks...

Comment: Is it called "newIfrane" on purpose?

Comment: You first show some code that works, in Firebug. Then say that it doesn't work on a click event and then shows us a function, that does not contain the code that worked nor any click event. Please update the question.

Comment: the code given above cancelFullScreen... is the code which works fine if executed using firebug console (ie. exiting from fullscreen)

Comment: @Tasos newIfrane is the id of iframe which loads my page in fullscreen

Comment: How exactly are you trying `exitfs()` in console? You're probably calling it under the context of top window instead of iframe.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was pointing our newIfraNe vs newIfraMe (looked like a typo)

Comment: @Passerby > thanks I changed it to parent.exitfs() and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested by **Passerby** I tried with the `parent.exitfs();` and it worked for me. hope it will help someOne...

Comment: hi ravi, I am doing the same thing but finding some problem can you please help me I am using the following code  in jsni..                               public static native void hello1(int counter)
  /*-{
     var body=$doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     var id=$doc.getElementById("vp");
     cancelFullscreen(id);
     function cancelFullscreen(id) 
       { 
          if (id.mozcancelFullScreen) 
          {
             id.mozcancelFullScreen();
          } 
         else
         if (id.webkitcancelFullScreen) 
          {
   id.webkitcancelFullScreen();
 }
 }   
   }-*/;

Comment: where counter is 1 initially and the id is for particular html id this  function is not working

Comment: what is the parent that you are taking about

Comment: parent of iframe (ie window.parent)

Comment: i have posted as an answer please check it once

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Clickfullpage implements ClickHandler
 {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
  {
    hello1(counter);
  }
}

public static native void hello1(int counter)
/*-{
 var body=$doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 var id=$doc.getElementById("vp");
 cancelFullscreen();
 function cancelFullscreen() 
   { 
      if ($doc.mozcancelFullScreen) 
      {
         $doc.mozcancelFullScreen();
      } 
     else
     if ($doc.webkitcancelFullScreen) 
      {
        $doc.webkitcancelFullScreen();
      }
   }   
}-*/;
```

Comment: please tell me where i am lacking

Comment: instead id try using $doc