# how to use functions to toggle full screen without user click

Tags: javascript, html

why cant i trigger fullscreen by just running a function?
(dont suggest functions) my problem is that running a perfectly correct function to trigger fullscreen onclick totally works but if i run the function by itself it dosent trigger fullscreen. is this a user consent problem because the browser or the developers of these web programming languages dont let you do certain things without user consent?

Comment: Can you exchange your code with this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_exitfullscreen.asp Might be you run in some sort of js error on specific devices/browsers. In your case you should always check if the function you want to use exists.

Comment: well its the exact same code

Comment: its not. They check if the function exists. give it a try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exit fullscreen onclick using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672561/how-to-exit-fullscreen-onclick-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

- `requestFullscreen` should be run on `document.documentElement`, while `exitFullscreen` should be run on `document`.
- If you're not on a webkit browser, the webkit function won't exist (the first one you call), and your function will error out before it calls the other functions. So you have to check to see if they exist.

The basic code to fix these issues is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_exitfullscreen.asp) and below:

```js
/* View in fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  /* Get the documentElement (<html>) to display the page in fullscreen */
  let elem = document.documentElement;
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Close fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Based on [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=exitfullscreen) and [this](https://caniuse.com/?search=requestFullscreen), if you want complete browser support, you'll also want to add a check for the `moz` prefixed functions, `mozRequestFullScreen` and `mozCancelFullScreen`.

Comment: That's actually a different issue, I didn't catch that. Check out the functions above -- openFullscreen uses `document.documentElement`, but closeFullscreen just uses `document`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: but my chrome works only with webkitfullscreen it shouldnt error out

Comment: oh ok i will try that

Comment: My answer should be updated with everything you need :)